# How do we reach from one point to another point when we have infinite set of "subdistances" to cover?

Tags: logic

Logically to reach from one point to another point when we have to cover infinitely many sub-distances,i.e.,first we have cover half the distance but to cover half the distance we have cover half of the half distance and so on. So how do we actully reach the final point. I also have the same type of question for a real number line:How do we reach from one number to another when there are infinitely many numbers in between

Comment: Look for "Zeno's Paradoxes" to find the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as "Zeno's paradox", so look up that term if you want to know more.

In our modern mathematical formalization of "distance" -- that is, the real numbers -- the answer to this question is that between event 1 (being present at one point) and event 2 (being present at another point), infinitely many events can occur (being present at e.g. the point halfway between the two points, and halfway between those points, and so on). This can happen despite the fact that between event 1 and event 2 we cover only a finite amount of distance, or that it takes a finite amount of time.

Comment: How is it possible to reach from point 1 to point 2 without covering all the points in between?

Comment: You do cover all the points in between. "Covering" just does not take a positive amount of time or distance, so even infinitely many points can take a finite amount of time or distance to cover.

Comment: what?I could not understand.

Comment: @MrAP It's just the same thing you're doing when you divide the line into infinitely many points - we can divide the time interval into infinitely many moments. Each point takes one moment; just as infinitely many points can form a finite distance, infinitely many moments can form a finite amount of time. Basically, the problem only arises because you're treating time as discrete (each event takes a positive amount of time) while treating space as continuous (any length can be subdivided further).